# Str to int function

Tags: python, function

I am supposed to write a function that lets the user put in any string of numbers and then turns that input into an int list (e.g "12635 1657 132651627"). However, I don't know how to change this bit of code so that the user can actually put something into the console. When I try to introduce a new variable Python says that there is no value assigned to it, and I do not know how to work around that. I want everything to be within the function. I managed to introduce a new variable before the start of the function but that's not really my aim here.

```
def Int_Split(a):
    List = []
    last = 0
    max = len(a)
    for i in range (max):
        if a[i] =="":
            nmbr = a[last:i]
            last = i+1
            List.append(int(nbmr))
        nmbr = a[last:]
        List.append(int(nmbr))
        return List
    print(List)
```

Comment: `nbmr` is supposed to be `nmbr`, right?

Comment: What do you mean by *"so that the user can actually put something into the console"*? Are you not aware of the `input()` function? If so, you should complete a Python tutorial before asking here. SO is not built to teach you the language. See also [How to ask and answer homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/4518341). Otherwise, if you're talking about an interactive Python session, the user can call `Int_Split("12635 1657 132651627")` for example, no?

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear what your issue is with adding a variable, or entirely what you're after. But if you are after converting `"12635 1657 132651627"` to `[12635, 1657, 132651627]`, that can be done very simply with:

```py
s = "12635 1657 132651627"
l = [int(x) for x in s.split()]
print(l)
```

Which yields:

```
[12635, 1657, 132651627]
```

---

Here is an example in a function:

```py
def main():
    print("input some numbers:")
    s = input()
    print([int(x) for x in s.split()])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Here we print the request for input, set the value given to `s`, then use a list comprehension to say: split a string on any whitespace, then give the integer value for each.

---

Here is a method without using `string.split()`:

```py
def sep(s):
    words = []
    word = ""
    for c in s:
        if c != " ":
            word += c
            continue
        words.append(word)
        word = ""
    else:
        words.append(word)
    return words


def main():
    print("input some numbers:")
    s = input()
    print([int(x) for x in sep(s)])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Here we have written a function called `sep`, which just iterates over characters in the given string until it finds a space or the end, each time adding that group of characters to a list of strings.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. Sadly I forgot to mention that I am supposed to do this in a way that does not use the split function but rather string slicing to give the integer list back to the user.

Comment: No worries. I added another function that may help.